# Is WearableListenerService better than Service with Data and Message Listeners?

Tags: android, wear-os

I have connected my application to Android Wear's Wearable Data Layer with a service that implements DataApi.DataListener, and MessageApi.MessageListener. This service allows me bind to my activities (WearableListenerService does not) and exchange data and messages between the apps perfectly fine. Recently I noticed that my service was getting terminated by the system which leads me to my questions:

1. Is WearableListenerService better than the above setup in that it is less likely to be terminated by the system under load?

2. When does a WearableListenerService get terminated by the sytstem if at all?

**I plan to have this as a long running service waiting for events to be triggered from an Android smartwatch

As an interesting note, I found an issue on the AOSP issue tracker covering how long the wearable service will last and it is marked as obsolete without an answer: [See this issue](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=73905)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your implementation of WearableListenerService will be invoked by the system when there is a message, data layer changes, etc for your app and it terminates relatively quickly when its job is done (shortly after you leave the scope) so the main advantage of using that is you don't have to have a long-running background service (which kills resources and battery) to listen to possible incoming data for your app.

Comment: By "main advantage of using that" are you referencing the WearableListenerService? Also my intention is to have a long running background service waiting for events on the watch, is there some kind of method Android is employing to start the WearableListenerService only when the datalayer notifies it that something has been changed? I'm still unclear since both my current implementation and WearableListenerService would be long running.

Comment: Yes, I mean WearableListenerService is the way to go and as I said, there is some magic there to do the binding and the rest when there is a message for your app. Unless you do something that you shouldn't be doing (or using startService() from within your code to start that), the WearableListenerService is not going to be a long-living service and please, do not use long-living services, specially when the WearableListenerService is there for you with all the features that you want without the drawbacks.

Comment: "Magic" xD I was afraid of that.  I'll leave figuring out what the magic is as another endeavor, thank you though.

Comment: It seems to me the implementation of WearableListenerService is not invoked if after starting the app, the device goes to the sleep mode and wakes up. How can I make sure the listener service will be automatically invoked even after going through a sleep/wakeup cycle? Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that is the case, can you build a simple test case to exhibit that? It should work regardless of going to sleep and then waking up.

Comment: Thank you very much for your quick reply! I tested it again and again. If the watch stays in the sleep mode for a long time, then after waking up, the listener service is not invoked. My code is based on
the Android sample code com/example/android/wearable/datalayer 
I have added android:exported="true" and android:enabled="true" to the service element in the manifest file.